# telethon doesn't get all the users, only ~90% of the user extracted from a public group

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

The code below works ok to extract users from TG groups, but I don't know why it only extracts like 90% of the users, not all of them... couldn't find a reason online.

I got the below code from a tutorial here: https://python.gotrained.com/scraping-telegram-group-members-python-telethon/

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty
import csv

api_id = 123456
api_hash = 'YOUR_API_HASH'
phone = '+111111111111'
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)

client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))


chats = []
last_date = None
chunk_size = 200
groups=[]
 
result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
             offset_date=last_date,
             offset_id=0,
             offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
             limit=chunk_size,
             hash = 0
         ))
chats.extend(result.chats)

for chat in chats:
    try:
        if chat.megagroup== True:
            groups.append(chat)
    except:
        continue

print('Choose a group to scrape members from:')
i=0
for g in groups:
    print(str(i) + '- ' + g.title)
    i+=1

g_index = input("Enter a Number: ")
target_group=groups[int(g_index)]

print('Fetching Members...')
all_participants = []
all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=True)

print('Saving In file...')
with open("members.csv","w",encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerow(['username','user id', 'access hash','name','group', 'group id'])
    for user in all_participants:
        if user.username:
            username= user.username
        else:
            username= ""
        if user.first_name:
            first_name= user.first_name
        else:
            first_name= ""
        if user.last_name:
            last_name= user.last_name
        else:
            last_name= ""
        name= (first_name + ' ' + last_name).strip()
        writer.writerow([username,user.id,user.access_hash,name,target_group.title, target_group.id])      
print('Members scraped successfully.')
```

Comment: Telegram doesn't want you to extract all members because the only reason you would need this would be considered spam.